# Swift: is possible to get the default size of UIImageView used by UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iOS app I am developing, it is necessary for the user to take a photo. As you can see from the following image

[image]

by default, when we take a photo with iOS camera app, then it is showed with a standard/default size (the one delimited by those 8 pins) and I would like my app to be the same. So, which size should I set my `UIImageView` into which the photo will be displayed? How can I get that default size in Swift?

Or maybe...which would be the best size to give to `UIImageview` to prevent the photo from being deformed too much?

Thank you very much for you attention

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` has a property called size which specifies width and height of the image. So you could size your `UIImageView` to those.

Alternatively, if you're using constraints or autoresize mask (flexible width, flexible height) simply don't set a size and the `UIImageView` will fill itself according to `contentMode`.

You must understand however that what you see in the image you posted is not the "original size" of the image. Someone decided that the `UIImageView` should be place at X distance from top and bottom margins, thus forcing an implicit size on the `UIImageView`